# Unable to get google analytics data_mcf data after a valid call, shows data but calling getConversionPathValue() return nothing

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

This is the data I get from google api explorer:

> "rows": [
>    [
>     {
>      "conversionPathValue": [
>       {
>        "interactionType": "CLICK",
>        "nodeValue": "(not set)"
>       }
>      ]
>     },
>     {
>      "primitiveValue": "6"
>     },
>     {
>      "primitiveValue": "4.0"
>     }

See Screenshot from google api explorer [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1jWd.png)

This is the successful api call using PHP dumping one of the result row

> array(425) {
>    [0] =>
>    class Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataRows#612 (7) {
>      protected $collection_key =>
>      string(19) "conversionPathValue"
>      protected $conversionPathValueType =>
>      string(55) "Google_Service_Analytics_McfDataRowsConversionPathValue"
>      protected $conversionPathValueDataType =>
>      string(5) "array"
>      public $primitiveValue =>
>      NULL
>      protected $internal_gapi_mappings =>
>      array(0) {
>      }
>      protected $modelData =>
>      array(3) {
>        [0] =>
>        array(1) {
>          ...
>        }
>        [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1jWd.png) =>
>        array(1) {
>          ...
>        }
>        [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcdLC.png) =>
>        array(1) {
>          ...
>        }
>      }
>      protected $processed =>
>      array(0) {
>      }
>    }

See Screenshot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcdLC.png)

This is my php script dumping conversionPathValue and primitiveValue but returns null

> ```
>            $options = array(
>                'dimensions' => 'mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath'
>            );
>            $metrics='mcf:totalConversions,mcf:totalConversionValue';
>            $q=$this->analytics_svc->data_mcf->>get('ga:'.$profile,$from,$to,$metrics,$options);
>            //echo var_dump($q);
>            if($q && isset($q->rows)){
>                $d=$q->getRows();
>                foreach($d as $v){
>                    echo var_dump($v->getConversionPathValue());
>                    echo var_dump($v->getPrimitiveValue());
>                    break;
>                }
>                return [];
>            }
> ```

Calling **getConversionPathValue**() and **getPrimitiveValue**() return nothing.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code not images of code.

Comment: I believe you are seeing it now @DalmTo